# How to load Apache Ignite Cache when reading from a text file

Tags: java, file, caching, gridgain, ignite

I created a file helloworld.txt. Now I'm reading from the file and then I want to load the contents of the file into the cache, and whenever the cache is updated, it should write to the file as well.

This is my code so far:

Please tell me what to do to load the cache and then write from the cache to the file, as the instructions are not clear from Apache Ignite documentation.

```
   import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
import java.io.FileReader; 
import java.io.IOException; 

import org.apache.ignite.Ignite; 
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteCache; 
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteDataStreamer; 
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteException; 
import org.apache.ignite.Ignition; 
import org.apache.ignite.examples.ExampleNodeStartup; 
import org.apache.ignite.examples.ExamplesUtils; 

public class FileRead { 
    /** Cache name. */ 
    private static final String CACHE_NAME = "FileCache"; 


    /** Heap size required to run this example. */ 
    public static final int MIN_MEMORY = 512 * 1024 * 1024; 

    /** 
     * Executes example. 
     * 
     * @param args Command line arguments, none required. 
     * @throws IgniteException If example execution failed. 
     */ 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IgniteException { 
        ExamplesUtils.checkMinMemory(MIN_MEMORY); 

        try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("examples/config/example-ignite.xml")) { 
            System.out.println(); 


            try (IgniteCache<Integer, String> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(CACHE_NAME)) { 
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

                try (IgniteDataStreamer<Integer, String> stmr = ignite.dataStreamer(CACHE_NAME)) { 
                    // Configure loader. 
                    stmr.perNodeBufferSize(1024); 
                    stmr.perNodeParallelOperations(8); 

                    ///FileReads(); 

                    try { 
                   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader 
                   (new FileReader("/Users/akritibahal/Desktop/helloworld.txt")); 
                   String str; 
                   int i=0; 
                   while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) { 
                  System.out.println(str); 
                  stmr.addData(i,str); 
                  i++;  
                      } 
                   System.out.println("Loaded " + i + " keys."); 
                     } 
                   catch (IOException e) { 
                   } 


                } 


            } 
        } 
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

For information on how to load the cache from a persistence store please refer to this page: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-loading

You have two options:

1. Start a client node, create `IgniteDataStreamer` and use it to load the data. Simply call `addData()` for each line in the file.
2. Implement `CacheStore.loadCache()` method, provide the implementation in the cache configuration and call `IgniteCache.loadCache()`.

Second approach will require to have the file on all server nodes, by there will be no communication between nodes, so most likely it will be faster.

Comment: I cannot figure out how to read from the cache, write to the file and update into the file. How do I get the key stored in this case??